# Can't execute bash script from shortcut

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, shortcut-keys

I try to execute a bash script from a shortcut set from the settings (`system settings > keyboard > shortcuts` or analogous), but it doesn't execute, although it works just fine from the terminal...

The script is as following :

```
#!/bin/bash
#"$1" should be a number from 0 to 5
if [ "$#" == 0 ]; then
   echo "Ce programme nécessite en argument le nombre d'étoiles (de 0 à 5) à attribuer à la chanson qui est en train de tourner dans Rhythmbox."
   exit
fi

rhythmbox-client --set-rating $1
notify-send "$1 étoiles" "$(rhythmbox-client --print-playing)" --expire-time=1000 --icon=starred
```

Then I set the shortcut, but it doesn't work (Noting happens). As said before, the same code executed from the terminal works great...

[image: screenshot]

Thanks for helping me !!

Comment: Have you tried the same command but included the program/interpreter? I.e. `bash`. For example: `bash ~/Scripts/rhythmbox-set-stars.sh 5`

Comment: No, it still doesn't... Neither with `bash -c '~/Scripts/rhythmbox-set-stars.sh 5'` Is there a way of debugging that ? Or do you have other ideas ?

Comment: You may laugh, but I restarted my session and it finally worked with the "bash" interpreter as you advised me :) As if the changes on an existing shortcut weren't taken into account :/ Thanks to you !! Note that I also used the real path with `/home/username/Scripts/rhythmbox......`

Answer (score 0):

The command defined in the pertinent field was missing the file interpreter (in this case: `bash`), and should have been using the files' absolute path.

Ergo: `bash /home/username/Scripts/rhythmbox-set-stars.sh 5`

A restart of the utility/session was required to apply the new values, presumably because values for the session were updated from the modified `.gconf`  file.